# Python: Turn on / off switch to start / stop loop instantly

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, pyautogui

```
import time
import pyautogui
from pyautogui import *
import keyboard
from PIL import ImageGrab 
import os
import win32api, win32con
import cv2
import pyperclip
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import pytesseract
 
##1340,182, 1777, 213
test = 0
 
def alertf1(c):
    global test
 
    while c == 1:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('f1'):  # if key 'f1' is pressed 
            print('f1 has been pressed')
            c = 0
            time.sleep(0.1)
            test = test + 1
            break
        else:
            print('checking if anything is destroyed')
            time.sleep(1)
            if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('destroy2.png', region=(1340,182, 1777, 230)):
                print('something got destroyed!')
                time.sleep(0.1)
                pyautogui.keyDown('ctrl')
                time.sleep(0.1)
                pyautogui.keyDown('tab')
                pyautogui.keyUp('ctrl')
                pyautogui.keyUp('tab')
                time.sleep(0.5)
                for char in '@':
                    pyperclip.copy(char)
                    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v', interval=0.1)
                    time.sleep(0.1)
                    pyautogui.write('everyone Enemies/Red Logs! Something has been destroyed.')
                    time.sleep(0.1)
                    pyautogui.press('enter')
                    time.sleep(5)
                    pyautogui.click(x=1860, y=50)
                    time.sleep(5)
            else:
                if keyboard.is_pressed('f1'):  # if key 'f1' is pressed 
                    print('f1 has been pressed')
                    c = 0
                    time.sleep(0.1)
                    test = test + 1
                    break
 
def on_press(key):
    global test
    if test > 0 and key == Key.f1:
        c = 0
    if key == Key.f1 and test == 0:
        print('before alert f1 pressed')
        time.sleep(0.1)
        test = test + 1
        alertf1(1)
    if key == Key.f1 and test > 1:
        test = 0
 
 
 
with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
        listener.join()
 
def main():
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print('on press going now')
        on_press(key)
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

my issue is that i want the turn on / off switch to use hte same key
and i can't think of a way to distinguish between when I press the key and when the program is simply on loop.

like F1 will start function alert, which will loop eternally, until I press F1, issue is that,  `if keyboard.is_pressed('f1'):`   isn't a great solution
because if code is somewhere else it wont recognize i pressed f1

Comment: Just define a flag called "alive" or something.  Have your key handler toggle that value (`alive = not alive`).  Then have your loop be `while alive:`.  As soon as you clear the flag, the loop ends.  Don't check the key in the loop, check the flag.  Side note, `F1` is a poor choice.  By convention, that means "HELP".

Comment: @TimRoberts What do you mean by "have your key handler toggle that value" how would I toggle the value of a flag by pressing F1? I am doing something similar to waht ur saying I think, where I do While C == 1 loop will continue but once I press F1 it will turn C = 0 issue is as I explained above though, sometimes F1 isn't detected if the code is past that point. (And I know F1 is "help" in IDLE and such but I intend to make a basic UI later on and distribute it, F keys are the easiest keybinds to turn each thing on/off)

Comment: The problem is that `keyboard.is_pressed('f1')` means "is it pressed RIGHT NOW"?   I don't think that's what you want.  You can't interrupt code immediately.  All you can do is set a flag that will be noticed eventually.  Your key checking should be entirely within `on_press`.

Comment: Take a look at the signals module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html